# sql multi-part identifier #TempTable.ColumnName could not be bound

Tags: sql, temp-tables

So I have a couple of temp tables I have created and am trying to move column contents from one table to another.

I populate `#TempTable` with values I'm gleaning from another table using a particular set of logic.  Once I'm done with the current section I want to move the contents of `#TempTable.ColumnName` to another temp table (`#Table1`) that is housing the collected results of the logic sets.

This is how I've done it:

```
SET @ExecStatement = 'Alter table #Table1 Add  ' + @ColumnName +'  varchar(250)';
EXEC (@ExecStatement)
set @ExecStatement = 'Update #Table1 set #Table1.'+@ColumnName+' = #TempTable.ColumnName ';
exec (@execStatement)
```

The error message appears on the second `SET` statement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: update without where condition?

Comment: @user1848739 I basically wanted to move all the contents from `#TempTable.ColumnName` to the new column `#Table1.ColumnName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing more than an invalid update statement -- SQL can't tell where to pull the data from. Try this as the second `set` statement:

```
set @ExecStatement = 'Update #Table1 set ' + @ColumnName + ' = tt.TempConv from #Table1 ta inner join #TempTable tt on tt.Id = ta.Id
```

(replace "Id" with the proper column name)

Comment: I don't understand the "Id" portion.  Would you explain at least briefly what that is doing.

Comment: Its joining the tables based on common ID fields.

Comment: Updating a table's contents based on the contents of another table requires joining the two tables, using syntax very similar to that of the SELECT statement. As I don't know the join criteria (how to identify which row in the "source" table is used to update the "target" table), I plugged in "Id" as a likely column name.

Comment: @PhilipKelley  what if I wanted the entire contents of the column from `#TempTable` to populate the entirety of the new column I just added to `#Table1` regardless of any of the rows.  basically considering these vertical tables.

Comment: `IF` "load the data of one-row one-column #TempTable" into (@NewColumn) in ALL rows of #Table1, `THEN` the basic form would be `UPDATE #Table1 set NewCol = (select TempConv from #TempTable)`

Comment: @PhilipKelley Thank you, I will try this in the morning!

Comment: @PhilipKelley  I believe that fixed my issue.  sorry it took so long to get back on and confirm.